How to make LLMs answer in certain pattern
How can I design the LLM program so that the LLM will answer in some preset pattern?For example, if I want to use the LLM to promote some products or collect some information from the user, what adjustment should I try on the LLM program? Thx~
I tried modifying the prompts but it doesn't work well when the user says something deviated from the conversation pattern, like when the user does not answer LLM's question.
